# Running animation in while loop

Tags: javascript, php, loops, animation, while-loop

I've been trying to do javascript animations in my while loop like forever but it is just the last row of my array that gets affected by the animation. I have very many rows that is going to be in the animation so saving all variables after my while loop will give me like 20 000 rows of manually saving if I do that.

Any tips or something would be great how to solve this as good as possible!
Thanks

EDIT- code //very simple example

```
<?php

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($data)){

$data = $rows['data'];

?>
<div id="square" style="height:50px; width:50px; background:yellow;" </div>
<script>

var data = '<?php echo $data; ?>';

setTimeout("call()",100);
function call() {

        if(data == "hello"){ //bad example 
        $('#square').animate({ left: (600), top: (200) }, 2000);                
        }
        else if(data == "bye"){
        $('#square').animate({ left: (100), top: (100) }, 2000);                
        }
        //etc... 
}
</script>

<?php
}
?>
```

something like this :)
It will output square in this example, in the amount of rows in my array. So basically I want all squares to be animated.

Comment: This sounds like you're forgetting to create a closure over the variable you're iterating with, but can we see some code?

Comment: The view is not re-rendered before the script has been executed. You need to use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) for the animation.

Comment: Ye i'm not really good at this. I'll get you some code in a sec! @PaulS.

Comment: A `while loop` is not asynchronous. You cannot do animation this way.

Comment: @remyabel it looks like the `while` is in _PHP_ then the animation is in _JS_, based upon the generated result.

Comment: @Paul I posted my comment before the edit.

Comment: Well, I'm happy for all tips. Don't know what to do really @PaulS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *PHP* `while` loop is generating multiple copies of a `<div>`, all of which have the same *id* `id="square"`. An *ID* is meant to be unique and therefore using the same *ID* multiple times may result in unexpected behaviour, such as only one of the elements referenced by it will be findable.

The attribute most-similar to an *ID* which is meant to be used multiple times is the *class* attribute.

Further, you're generating a `<script>` with a *function* named `call` multiple times. Each time the code in the `<script>` gets executed, it will cause the old `call` *function* to be overwritten by the new one. This means that only the most recent will exist in memory.

Try separating your *JavaScript* from your *PHP*, and moving away from using the same *id* multiple times. This should improve the validity of your code and resolve your problem.

As a final note, passing a *String* into `setTimeout` causes it to behave like `eval`, this behaviour is not encouraged. Pass your function into it directly instead.

Comment: Yes, you have a point there. Stupid that i didn't realized that until now. Will try to change some things now. @PaulS.

Comment: I have changed it so the div now gets different ids depending on which row it is. I now have a setTimeout which makes the animation run. Do you think it is possible to make it start with a button? 
Also i don't know how to move the script outside the row without that I have to do alot of saving of my values which I get from my rows.
And what do you mean with the last sentence? :) @PaulS.